# What is the recommended way close IO resources declared as instance variables

Tags: java, java-io, finalize

In some of the Java classes I see the IO resources declared as instance varibles and are being used in multiple methods.How can I close them?Few Suggested finalize() and they also say that it is not recommended. May I know if there is any better approach for this.?
Ex:

```
 public class test{
      private PrintWriter writer=null;
      public test(){
       createWriter();
}
      public void log(){
        writer.write("test");
        writer.flush();
      }
      public void createWriter(){
        writer=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file")));
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'd just do like all the standard Streams and Writers wrapping other Streams and Writers: make the class implement Closeable, and thus have a close() method that can be called automatically by the try-with-resources statement. And document that, of course.

Comment: Thank you! this problem is from an existing project with a large code base.Do I need to change(add try-with) everywhere where the object is being created or is there any other way through which I can close it without making any changes outside of this class.

Comment: You're not forced to use the try-with-resources statement. The alternative is to close in a finally block. But there is nothing that you can do to make the code call close() magically without changing the code.

Comment: Got it.Thank you.Was trying to figure out if I can do this without making any changes outside of the class(_like by adding finalize() or anyother alternative_).Will go ahead with the try-with resources.thanks once again.:)

Answer (score 1):

Implements `AutoCloseable` in your class and override `close()` method and close all your IO related resources in this `close()` method.

Now if you are using Java 7 you can create a reference to your class using try with resource and JVM will automatically call close method of your class.

As you can see in the code of FilterReader class,

```
public abstract class FilterReader extends Reader {
    protected Reader in;
    //......Other code, and then
    public void close() throws IOException {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

And if you write

```
try(FileReader fr = new FileReader("filename")){
    // your code
}
```

and you are done JVM will automatically close it

Answer (score 0):

There shoud be some kind of destructor. In junit for example (as you are naming your class "test") you have  @AfterClass annotation to do your clean-up in such annotated method.

Answer (score 0):

You just close it manually after you use it.

```
public class PrintWriterDemo {
private PrintWriter writer;
public PrintWriterDemo() {
    writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
}
public void log(String msg) {
    writer.write(msg + "\n");
    writer.flush();
}

public void close() {
    System.out.println("print writer closed.");
    writer.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintWriterDemo demo = new PrintWriterDemo();
    demo.log("hello world");
    demo.close();
}
```

}